# Is there a way to initialize TinyMCE in a test to get a properly initialized tinyMCE object without starting a browser

Tags: javascript, tinymce

We would like to write tests for our TinyMCE integration. We do some text manipulation inside TinyMCE so, we would like to have a test that simulates that.
However, it seems like the initialization of TinyMCE doesn't work as the activeEditor of TinyMCE doesn't have a body after the initialization.
We are using TinyMCE 6.5

We initialize tinyMCE like this:

```
import { it, beforeEach, afterEach, describe, expect } from "vitest";
import './matchMedia';
import 'tinymce';

describe("TinyMce", function () {

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Create a new textarea element
        var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
        textarea.id = 'tinyMCETextArea';
        // Append the textarea to the body
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);

        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#tinyMCETextArea',
        });

        let body = tinymce.activeEditor.getBody();
        //body == null here, which isn't what we would expect
    });
});
```

`tinymce.activeEditor` is present and we can work with it. However 'getBody()' returns null and we are not sure why. We tried to await `tinymce.init` but it actually never properly finishes.

Our best guess is, that because there is no browser instance open, the initialization of tinyMCE doesn't finish/work. But we don't have a way to prove that.